# Symfony2 knp-paginator not sorting my products

Tags: php, symfony, sorting, pagination

So the knp bundle works fine with paginating my products, however when it comes to sorting I am not getting any errors, but the products just wont sort.

```
<th{% if pagination.isSorted('a.price') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Price/Lowest', 'a.price') }}</th>
```

So when I am trying to sort, I don't get any errors, the response is 200 and the URL changes with this:

```
?sort=a.pc&direction=asc&page=1
```

But the products are not sorted. Is this some kind of a bug? The documentation isn't very clear with the sorting stuff, but I don't think I am doing something wrong..

Here is the price field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $price;
```

P.S. Sorting doesn't work with other parameters too, not only price..

The action:

```
public function newProductsAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $products = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findBy(array('status' => 1), array('id' => 'ASC'), 15);
    $locale = $this->get('translator')->getLocale();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
    $skin = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Skin')->findOneBy(array('status' => 1));

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $products,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        9/*limit per page*/
    );
```

Comment: Show us how you make your queries from the controller and the repository class

Comment: for the pagination you need to pass a querybuilder to the paginator paginate method instead of the product to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using the findBy() method to get an array of Product entities.
This method fires the query and The pagination bundle cannot change your query anymore. Instead you should add your own ProductRepository class and write a method that just returns a DQL query.

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findProducts()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->where('p.status=1');
        return $qb->getQuery(); // WITHOUT ->getResult(); !!
    }
}
```

In your controller you get something like:

```
$query = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findProducts();

// ...

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $query,
    $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    9/*limit per page*/
);
```

Also keep in mind that the array with product entities is in de $pagination variabele and not in the $products variabele anymore. (you could change $pagination to $products OR change your twig template)